# Format of long strings in VBA IDE

Tags: vba, excel, encoding, utf-8

I'm writing a macro which takes a VBA code module, exports it, reads the exported file into a 64 bit string and saves this as a constant in another VBA module (by using `VBComponent.codeModule.InsertLines`). For some reason, my 64 bit strings have linebreaks every 72 characters in the IDE (see image)
[image: Linebreak]

For some reason the strings generated from exporting files do this, but not a string generated with `String(500,"a")`. I wonder whether anyone can provide any insight into this behaviour, I would like the entire expression to be on a single line.

```
Sub test() 'in a module named "testModule"
    exampleString = String(500, "a")
    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Item("testModule").codeModule.InsertLines _
    2, "Const str As String = """ & exampleString & """"
End Sub
```

gives

```
Sub test() 'in a module named "testModule"
Const str As String = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
    exampleString = String(500, "a")
    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Item("testModule").codeModule.InsertLines _
    2, "Const str As String = """ & exampleString & """"
End Sub
```

while

```
exampleString = Base64EncodedModule()
```

results in that bizarre behaviour in the image. Maybe there's something really obvious I'm missing, but the base64 string *looks* exactly like something I could type, so I don't know why it's being split over multiple lines when I write it to the `codeModule` programmatically.

---

A minimum bit of code

```
Function Base64EncodedModule() As String
    'export module
    Dim exportPath As String: exportPath = Environ("temp") & "\" & "tempModule.bas"
    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Module1").Export exportPath
    'read file as bytes
    Dim inStream As Object: Set inStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    inStream.Open
    inStream.Type = 1 'Binary file
    inStream.LoadFromFile exportPath
    'encode as base 64
    Dim objXML As MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Dim objNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement

    Set objXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Set objNode = objXML.createElement("b64")

    objNode.DataType = "bin.base64"
    objNode.nodeTypedValue = inStream.Read() 'read bytes from file
    Base64EncodedModule = objNode.text

    Kill exportPath 'remove temp file
End Function
```

Comment: It's not possible to fit them in a single line. I can't recall the character limit of a single-line-input but you can fit it in multilines by placing `" & _ ` at the end of each line to make it valid. There is a limitation of creating multilines as well. That may be 20 or something

Comment: @SIM maximum length of a physical line of code in the VBE is 1024 characters.

Comment: I did not downvote, but I believe it's because you could have easily stopped your code before it calls `InsertLines` and observed that the new lines are already in the string.

Comment: @GSerg yes perhaps, although because I access the VBProject when exporting the files to read, I actually can't stop the code before the `InsertLines` statement - I tried printing the string instead, but thought the newlines where just how the immediate window formatted it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string is [base64 encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) and can contain line separators every n blocks of 4 chars depending on the encoding algorithm. It seems to be the case here.

So either remove the line breaks with `Replace` or use a decoding/encoding algorithm without line break like this one:

```
'
' Base 64 encoding '
'

Public Sub FromBase64(Text As String, Out() As Byte)
  Dim b64(0 To 255) As Byte, str() As Byte, i&, j&, v&, b0&, b1&, b2&, b3&
  Out = ""
  If Len(Text) Then Else Exit Sub

  str = " ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/"
  For i = 2 To UBound(str) Step 2
    b64(str(i)) = i \ 2
  Next

  ReDim Out(0 To ((Len(Text) + 3) \ 4) * 3 - 1)
  str = Text & String$(2, 0)

  For i = 0 To UBound(str) - 7 Step 2
    b0 = b64(str(i))

    If b0 Then
      b1 = b64(str(i + 2))
      b2 = b64(str(i + 4))
      b3 = b64(str(i + 6))
      v = b0 * 262144 + b1 * 4096& + b2 * 64& + b3 - 266305
      Out(j) = v \ 65536
      Out(j + 1) = (v \ 256&) Mod 256
      Out(j + 2) = v Mod 256
      j = j + 3
      i = i + 6
    End If
  Next

  If b2 = 0 Then
    Out(j - 3) = (v + 65) \ 65536
    j = j - 2
  ElseIf b3 = 0 Then
    Out(j - 3) = (v + 1) \ 65536
    Out(j - 2) = ((v + 1) \ 256&) Mod 256
    j = j - 1
  End If

  ReDim Preserve Out(j - 1)
End Sub

Public Function ToBase64(data() As Byte) As String
  Dim b64(0 To 63) As Byte, str() As Byte, i&, j&, v&, n&
  n = UBound(data) - LBound(data) + 1
  If n Then Else Exit Function

  str = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/"
  For i = 0 To 127 Step 2
    b64(i \ 2) = str(i)
  Next

  ReDim str(0 To ((n + 2) \ 3) * 8 - 1)

  For i = LBound(data) To UBound(data) - (n Mod 3) Step 3
    v = data(i) * 65536 + data(i + 1) * 256& + data(i + 2)
    str(j) = b64(v \ 262144)
    str(j + 2) = b64((v \ 4096) Mod 64)
    str(j + 4) = b64((v \ 64) Mod 64)
    str(j + 6) = b64(v Mod 64)
    j = j + 8
  Next

  If n Mod 3 = 2 Then
    v = data(n - 2) * 256& + data(n - 1)
    str(j) = b64((v \ 1024&) Mod 64)
    str(j + 2) = b64((v \ 16) Mod 64)
    str(j + 4) = b64((v * 4) Mod 64)
    str(j + 6) = 61 ' = '
  ElseIf n Mod 3 = 1 Then
    v = data(n - 1)
    str(j) = b64(v \ 4 Mod 64)
    str(j + 2) = b64(v * 16 Mod 64)
    str(j + 4) = 61 ' = '
    str(j + 6) = 61 ' = '
  End If

  ToBase64 = str
End Function
```