# How can I send an image in the email body from Thunderbird with Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, thunderbird

How can I send an image in the email body from Thunderbird with Excel VBA?

```vb
thundnd = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe " & "-compose " & Chr(34) & _
  "to='" & email & "'," & "subject='" & subj & "'," & "body='" & body & "'," & "format=1," & Chr(34)    
            
Call Shell (thundnd, vbNormalFocus)
```

I want to send an image, not in the attachment, but inside the HTML body of the email.

In VBA I encode the image in String using **EncodeBase64.**
In the results, I get a jump to the next line after 72 characters.

```
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/4RCERXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABAE7AAIAAAAGAAAISodp
AAQAAAABAAAIUJydAAEAAAAMAAAQcOocAAcAAAgMAAAAPgAAAAAc6gAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

I insert it into the body

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/4RCERXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABAE7AAIAAAAGAAAISodp"
aaqaaaabaaaiujydaaeaaaamaaaqcoocaacaaagmaaaapgaaaaac6gaaaagaaaaaaaaaaaaa="" e.t.c.
```

[as in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49371207/format-of-long-strings-in-vba-ide).

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple answer.

Edit encoded string and replace characters: vbLf (Line feed)

```
correctPicture = Replace(Mid(bytes, 1), vbLf, "")
```

Now it is working.